# Is it possible to install 32 bit webcam driver (made for windows xp) on 32 bit Lubuntu?

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, camera

I have an old webcam want to use it on a old laptop. Previously Windows Xp was installed on it. I installed Lubuntu and removed Windows entirely.

However driver installer has .exe format. How can I install the driver? Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried plugging it in. That has always worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to install a Windows XP device driver on linux.

You can start [here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam)
to find support for your webcam.

Or search for your webcam model [here (https://askubuntu.com/search?q=webcam)](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=webcam)